# Java Getting Clock To Update

Tags: java, swing, timer, project, clock

I'm working on a project for school, and I'm sorta stuck. I have written a program the displays the current time, but I can't figure out how to get it to update as the time changes. If some could help me, or point me in some direction to get started, your help will be appreciated. I will post what I have written so far below.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;


public class Project2 extends JFrame{
public static void main(String[] args){
    Project2 myFrame = new Project2();
    myFrame.pack();
    myFrame.setTitle("Digital Clock");
    myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    myFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    myFrame.setVisible(true);


}//main()

public Project2(){
System.out.println(currentTime());
JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
p1.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
JLabel time = new JLabel(currentTime());
time.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman", Font.BOLD, 20));
time.setForeground(Color.blue);
p1.add(time);
this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
this.add(p1, BorderLayout.CENTER);

}

public String currentTime(){
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
   int hours = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
   int minutes = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
   int seconds = calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);
   int aP = calendar.get(Calendar.AM_PM);
   String currentTime = hours+":"+checkTime(minutes)+":"+checkTime(seconds)+" "+amP(aP);
   return currentTime;
 }

public String checkTime(int t){
    String time1;
    if (t < 10){
        time1 = ("0"+t);
        }
    else{
        time1 = (""+t);
        }
    return time1;
}

public String amP(int ap){
    String amPm;
    if( ap == 0)
        amPm = "AM";
    else
        amPm = "PM";
    return amPm;
}



}//Project2
```

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Have a look at [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) and [TimerTask](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html) classes. Then use these classes to update the JLabel's text.

Comment: Can I have another hint or something, I'm so lost right now. I looked at the Timer class, but I'm not sure how to implement into my program.

Comment: -1 the Timer to use in Swing is javax.swing.Timer, not the one in util

Answer (score 1):

Declare JPanel and JLabel as global variables and add the following lines at the end of the 
constructor

```
ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                    System.out.println(currentTime());
                    time.setText(currentTime());
                }
            };
            Timer t = new Timer(1000, taskPerformer);
            t.start();
```

Here is the complete code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.Timer;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.*;

public class DigitalClock extends JFrame {

    private JPanel p1;
    private JLabel time;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DigitalClock myFrame = new DigitalClock();
        myFrame.pack();
        myFrame.setTitle("Digital Clock");
        myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        myFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        myFrame.setVisible(true);

    }// main()

    public DigitalClock() {
        System.out.println(currentTime());
        p1 = new JPanel();
        p1.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        time = new JLabel(currentTime());
        time.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman", Font.BOLD, 20));
        time.setForeground(Color.blue);
        p1.add(time);
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.add(p1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                System.out.println(currentTime());
                time.setText(currentTime());
            }
        };
        Timer t = new Timer(1000, taskPerformer);
        t.start();
    }

    public String currentTime() {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hours = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minutes = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        int seconds = calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);
        int aP = calendar.get(Calendar.AM_PM);
        String currentTime = hours + ":" + checkTime(minutes) + ":"
                + checkTime(seconds) + " " + amP(aP);
        return currentTime;
    }

    public String checkTime(int t) {
        String time1;
        if (t < 10) {
            time1 = ("0" + t);
        } else {
            time1 = ("" + t);
        }
        return time1;
    }

    public String amP(int ap) {
        String amPm;
        if (ap == 0)
            amPm = "AM";
        else
            amPm = "PM";
        return amPm;
    }

}// Project2
```

Comment: I must not be doing something right because I get the error when I try to compile. it says error: <identifier> expected t.start();

Comment: Currently its back to the state it was at when I first posted it, was tying some things other people suggested, but that got me no where.

Answer (score 0):

I am agree with Pradeep, you must use a timer, for example you can define a timer, and make that a method is call every 1 second, in this method you can update the displayed time...